# Issue with HTML generated by loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I'm having some issues creating a list of collapsible elements. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Q63Dx/2/)

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 384">Kaoweuzax-Xrjamjhxteaq</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
            <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 1991">Eovwurxmpgmz 6.b</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 383">Uxiuhbgbt0.5-Rdsopvxc Fucxbhivs</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 1990">Zekgyfrmc-Tpuduwzr Idkudowbi</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="projectscontainer">
    <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 394">Lyxiyp</span><br>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2108">Kdvdz</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2109">Derqi-AA_Boejbvr</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="srcprojects">
        <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Yhdju-SkneLxiyuz</span><br>
    </div>
```

jQuery here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".projectscontainer").click(function(){
      $(this).children('.srcprojects').toggle();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$result_rules = $db->query("SELECT rules.source_id, rules.destination_id, dest.project AS dest_project, src.project AS src_project, src.    pk_id as src_id
        FROM dbo.FFC_Rules rules
        INNER JOIN dbo.FFC_Destination dest
            ON dest.pk_id=rules.destination_id
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FFC_Source src
            ON src.pk_id=rules.source_id
        ORDER BY dest.project ASC");

$last_dest = false;
$last_src = false;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_rules)){  
    if ($row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest) {
        $last_dest=$row['destination_id'];
        echo "<div class='projectscontainer'>";
        echo    "-<span class='item destproject' title='ID: ".$row['destination_id']."'>".$row['dest_project']."</span>";
        echo    "<br>";
    }
        echo    "<div class='srcprojects'>";
        echo        "<div class='arrow-right'></div>";
    if ($row['src_id'] === null) {
        echo        " Source ID for Destination ID ".$row['destination_id']." is NULL ";
    } else {
        echo        "<span class='item srcproject' title='ID: ".$row['src_id']."'>".$row['src_project']."</span>";
    }
    echo            "<br>";
    echo        "</div>";
    echo    "</div>";
}
?>
```

Right now it works if there's only 1 srcproject under the destproject, but I want all children (srcproject) of the destproject to be hidden when the destproject is clicked.

In the third projectscontainer div, the closing div tag is added before all the srcprojects are printed out. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is something weird in your loop while. You are openning `<div class='projectscontainer'>` on a specific condition : `$row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest`. But your seems to close the div without any condition. I think this generate bad HTML which browser try to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something weird in your loop. You are openning

```
<div class='projectscontainer'>
```

on this condition

```
if ($row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest) {
```

But you are not closing the `<div>` on the same condition, you are closing the `<div>` withou any condition. I think the generated HTML is not well formed and your browser try to do his best to fix it (in vain).

Try:

```
// Initialize the last dest
$last_dest = false;

// Loop on each result
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_rules)) {

    // Check if the section is changing or if we are at the begining
    if ($row['destination_id'] !== $last_dest || $last_dest === false) {

        // Close the previous projectscontainer tag if we are not at the begining of the process
        if ($last_dest !== false)
            echo "</div>";

        // Update the last dest
        $last_dest = $row['destination_id'];

        // Open the new projectscontainer 
        echo "<div class='projectscontainer'>";
        echo    "-<span class='item destproject' title='ID: ".$row['destination_id']."'>".$row['dest_project']."</span>";
        echo    "<br>";
    }

    // Print the sub block
    echo "<div class='srcprojects'>";
    echo "    <div class='arrow-right'></div>";

    if ($row['src_id'] === null) {
        echo "Source ID for Destination ID ".$row['destination_id']." is NULL ";
    } else {
        echo        "<span class='item srcproject' title='ID: ".$row['src_id']."'>".$row['src_project']."</span>";
    }

    echo "<br />";
    echo "</div>";
}

// At the end at the process, close the last projectscontainer
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all the children of the last project to be hidden, in that case you have to change your HTML content to this

```
    <div class="projectscontainer"> <span class="item destproject" title="ID: 394">Lyxiyp</span>
<br>
<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2108">Kdvdz</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2109">Derqi-AA_Boejbvr</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Yhdju-SkneLxiyuz</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Fcnlw-YTR-Orzqksr</span>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Awhsa-DT</span>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Kxqda-WuxkorctkwmWlioamud</span>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="srcprojects">
    <div class="arrow-right"></div> <span class="item srcproject" title="ID: 2110">Jnlps-NcsgfdlbpzaAhdthi</span>
    <br>

</div>
```